# create a control with same Id after destroying it

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have destroyed a control view and i want to create it with same Id. How to 
achieve that?

```
       var sheetNumber = this.getView().byId("shtNum");
       sheetNumber.destroy();

       if(!sheetNumber){
          var sheetView = new sap.ui.xmlview({
                id:"shtNum",
                viewName:"com.prowess.view.PieceId"
          });
        this.createId(sheetView);
      }
```

but it is showing sheetView is undefined.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Even if you call `destroy` on a control, the variable will still contain a reference to the destroyed control, so your `if` check will never work.

You should simply remove the `if` from your code since the check is basically useless. Optionally, you can also "undefine" the original variable, though there isn't really much point in doing it.

```
var sheetNumber = this.getView().byId("shtNum");
sheetNumber.destroy();
sheetNumber = undefined; // optional

var sheetView = new sap.ui.xmlview({
    id:"shtNum",
    viewName:"com.prowess.view.PieceId"
});
```

Also your line with `createId` is incorrect. If you are trying to get the ID of the view you just created, use this:

```
sheetView.getId();
```

Comment: ThankYou  #TiiJ7.

Comment: @RamyaSree Please consider to accept this answer if it was helpful to resolve the issue. See _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 0):

![code][1]

If you are using IE 12 then use let. let is working within a scope.

[Check more about let keyword][2]

Or use below code maybe it works.

```
   var sheetNumber = this.getView().byId("shtNum");
if(delete window.sheetNumber){
    var sheetView = new sap.ui.xmlview({
        id:"shtNum",
        viewName:"com.prowess.view.PieceId"
  });
this.createId(sheetView);
}
```

**Code Update :**
Delete is not working directly because delete removing a reference in side object so we need to use full var FQN.
Updated code is working on my system. 
We need to delete var in windows object using delete operator. Thanks for suggestion @ user3808826

Comment: Still sheetView undefined

Comment: Getting Type Error i.indexof is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to delete the instance of the control

```
   var sheetNumber = this.getView().byId("shtNum");
   sheetNumber.destroy();
   delete sheetNumber;

   if (!sheetNumber) {
      var sheetView = new sap.ui.xmlview({
        id:"shtNum",
        viewName:"com.prowess.view.PieceId"
      });
    this.createId(sheetView);
  }
```